# Solve a system of differential equations using Euler's method

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of ordinary differential equations with Euler's method, but when I try to print velocity I get

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

and instead of printing numbers I get `nan` (not a number). I think the problem might be when defining the acceleration, but I don't know for sure, I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

```
from numpy import *
from math import pi,exp

d=0.0005*10**-6
a=[]

while d<1.0*10**-6 :
    d=d*2
    a.append(d)

D=array(a)

def a_particula (D,x, v, t):
    cc=((1.00+((2.00*lam)/D))*(1.257+(0.400*exp((-1.10*D)/(2.00*lam)))))
    return (g-((densaire*g)/densparticula)-((mu*18.0*v)/(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00))))

def euler (acel,D, x, v, tv, n=15):
    nv, xv, vv = tv.size, zeros_like(tv), zeros_like(tv)
    xv[0], vv[0] = x, v
    for k in range(1, nv):
        t, Dt = tv[k-1], (tv[k]-tv[k-1])/float(n)
        for i in range(n):
            a = acel(D,x, v, t)
            t, v = t+Dt, v+a*Dt
            x = x+v*Dt
        xv[k], vv[k] = x, v
    return (xv, vv)

g=(9.80)    
densaire= 1.225         
lam=0.70*10**-6         
densparticula=1000.00
mu=(1.785*10**-5)       
tv = linspace(0, 5, 50)
x, v = 0, 0 #initial conditions


for j in range(len(D)):

    xx, vv = euler(a_particula, D[j], x, v, tv)

    print(D[j],xx,vv)
```

Comment: Note that you are using symplectic Euler despite it being a non-conservative system. Replace the Euler step with `t,x,v = t+Dt, x+v*Dt, v+a*Dt` to implement the correct numerical method. Check again the physics of your equation, the other force terms should be dominated by the gravity term. The second (buoyancy?)  is smaller, the third (friction) is obscenely larger leading to positive feedback (with a negative factor, thus oscillating) in the velocity evolution. If you can not find the error, give an accounting of the physical laws used to derive the force terms.

Comment: Or use a time step commensurate with the (inverse of the) Lipschitz constant. Which means `Dt=1e-8` or smaller. `tv=linspace(0,5e-4,50)` and `n=1000` works. Use methods for stiff systems (trapezoidal method, other implicit methods) to be able to use larger time steps.

Answer (score 4):

In future it would be helpful if you included the full warning message in your question - it will contain the line where the problem occurs:

```
tmp/untitled.py:15: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  return (g-((densaire*g)/densparticula)-((mu*18.0*v)/(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00))))
```

[Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) occurs when the magnitude of a variable exceeds the largest value that can be represented. In this case, `double_scalars` refers to a 64 bit float, which has a maximum value of:

```
print(np.finfo(float).max)
# 1.79769313486e+308
```

So there is a scalar value in the expression:

```
(g-((densaire*g)/densparticula)-((mu*18.0*v)/(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00))))
```

that is exceeding ~1.79e308. To find out which one, you can use [`np.errstate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) to raise a `FloatingPointError` when this occurs, then catch it and start the [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

```
    ... 
    with errstate(over='raise'):
        try:
            ret = (g-((densaire*g)/densparticula)-((mu*18.0*v)/(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00))))
        except FloatingPointError:
            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()
        return ret
    ...
```

From within the debugger you can then check the values of the various parts of this expression. The overflow seems to occur in:

```
(mu*18.0*v)/(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00))
```

The first time the warning occurs, `(cc*densparticula*  (D**2.00)` evaluates as 2.3210168586496022e-12, whereas `(mu*18.0*v)` evaluates as -9.9984582297025182e+299.

Basically you are dividing a very large number by a very small number, and the magnitude of the result is exceeding the maximum value that can be represented. This might be a problem with your math, or it might be that your inputs to the function are not reasonably scaled.

Answer (score 3):

Your system reduces to

```
dv/dt = a = K - L*v
```

with `K` about `10` and `L` ranging between, at first glance `1e+5` to `1e+10`. The actual coefficients used confirm that:

```
D=1.0000e-09        K= 9.787995      L=1.3843070e+08
D=3.2000e-08        K= 9.787995      L=4.2570244e+06
D=1.0240e-06        K= 9.787995      L=9.0146813e+04
```

---

The Euler step for the velocity is

```
v[j+1]=v[j]+(K-L*v[j])*dt =(1-L*dt)*v[j] + K*dt
```

For anything resembling the intended friction effect, i.e., the velocity falling to `K/L` one needs that `abs(1-L*dt)<1`, and if possible `0<1-L*dt<1`, that is, `dt < 1/L`. Which means here that `dt < 1e-10`.

To be able to use larger time steps you need to use methods for **stiff** differential equations, which means **implicit methods**. The most simple ones are the implicit Euler method, the midpoint method and the trapezoidal method.

Because of the linearity, the midpoint and trapezoidal method amount to the same formula

```
v[j+1] = v[j] + dt * ( K - L*(v[j]+v[j+1])/2 )
```

or

```
v[j+1] = ( (1-L*dt/2)*v[j] + K*dt ) / (1+L*dt/2)
```

---

Of course, the most simple method is to just **exactly integrate the ODE**

```
(-L*v')/(K-L*v)=-L  =>  K-L*v(t)=C*exp(-L*t), C=K-L*v(0)

v(t)=K/L + exp(-L*t)*(v(0)-K/L)
```

which integrates to

```
x(t)=x(0)+K/L*t+(1-exp(-L*t))/L*(v(0)-K/L).
```

---

**Alternatively** it is possible that you made an error in transcribing the physical laws into formulas so that the magnitudes of the constants are all wrong.